# numpy transforming RGB image to YIQ color space

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, matrix, multidimensional-array

For a class, I need to transform RGB image into YIQ.
We have been told that the conversion can be made by:

[image: transforming rgb to yiq]

I started to write a messy code with loops to have the matrix multiplication and then I found out a function

```
 skimage.color.yiq2rgb(imYIQ)
```

and when I looked inside to see what they were doing I saw the following (I'm copying stuff so it will be more clear):

```
yiq_from_rgb = yiq_from_rgb = np.array([[0.299,      0.587,        0.114],
                                 [0.59590059, -0.27455667, -0.32134392],
                                 [0.21153661, -0.52273617, 0.31119955]])
return np.dot(arr, yiq_from_rgb.T.copy())
```

when `arr` is just the RGB pic as a matrix

I'm trying to understand why this works? why do they take the Transpose matrix? (.T)
And how exactly does the dot product work when the `arr` shape is different than the yiq_from_rgb?

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html#numpy.dot) - `For 2-D arrays it is equivalent to matrix multiplication,`.

Comment: Maybe it needs to be transposed because the image array is *transposed* from the required conversion spec?

Comment: [Coordinate Conventions](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/numpy_images.html#coordinate-conventions) - the image array dimensions are (row, col, ch). so a 5x10 image would have a shape of (10, 5, 3); the red channel would be `arr[:,:,0]`, blue is `arr[:,:,1]` ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your reference figure containing the matrix for the conversion, the transformation matrix is on the left of the RGB channels. So, for the first pixel in your RGB image, let's call it `(p1r, p1g, p1b)` corresponding to R, G, B channels respectively, we need to multiply with the transformation matrix and sum the results like:

```
y1y = (0.299*p1r + 0.587*p1g + 0.114*p1b)
y1i = (0.596*p1r - 0.275*p1g - 0.321*p1b)
y1q = (0.212*p1r - 0.523*p1g + 0.311*p1b)
```

where `(y1y,y1i,y1q)` is the value for the first pixel in the resulting YIQ image, after rounding/taking `int`. We do the same kind of multiplication for all the pixels in the whole RGB image and obtain the desired YIQ image.

Now, since they do this whole implementation using `np.dot(arr, yiq_from_rgb.T)`, to have the weighting work out correctly the transformation matrix needs to be transposed. And `copy` is just to have a dedicated of the transposed transformation matrix for the purpose of this conversion.

Also, notice that contrary to your figure, in `np.dot()` the RGB array is on the left of transformation matrix.

Comment: I've seen some *indications* that the result also needs to be divided by 255.