# converting RGB to YIQ with matrix multiplication python

Tags: python, image-processing, rgb, matrix-multiplication

I want to converse image of 700 on 500 pixels encoded in RGB space to YIQ space, for that I need to use matrix multiplication in the form

> P = A*T

When P is a vector representing YIQ color space, T is a vector representing RGB space and A is a constant 3X3 matrix. The problem is that this is working for each pixel alone, how can I make this multiplication without the need of looping over all pixels?

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/q/46990838/2836621